# What does the verb cesse mean in "triste si cesse mai"

Tags: verbs, phrases

I know this is an Italian phrase that means saddness yes but sh""t no? But I couldn't find its translation. What does *cesse* mean here?

Comment: Where did you find the phrase? And is profanity necessary?

Comment: Sorry didn't know it is a curse.  I saw it on instagram when someone noted that though she is sad she will not wear any"cesse" closes.

Comment: I was referring to “sh*t”. But “cesse” means nothing in Italian.

Comment: She translated it to "sh*t" it was an italian teacher.  that was why i did not find the translation maybe. Thnks

Comment: Is the phrase exactly “triste si cesse mai”? (Without inverted commas it's hard to parse your question.) Like this, it's not Italian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase is *triste sì, cesse mai*, it is not elegant, is a popular, vulgar term, but it is often used.

And in a dictionary there aren't only *chic* words.

*Cesse* is a corruption for *cesso*, forgive me the inelegance, but it is Italian: it is a vulgar term for *toilet*. It has also a figurative sense and means *very ugly*, if referred to a person.

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cesso2/

*Triste sì, cesse mai* is the phrase of a person who says that, even if going through a hard time,   will not neglect her/his appearance.

Comment: _Mentioning_ scurrilous language if there is a reason for it is of course never a problem, as opposed to _using_ it, and “cesso” is not even especially scurrilous, it's just one of several synonyms of “bagno”, “latrina” etc., apart from its figurative uses. That said, where do they say “cesse” for “cesso”?

Comment: Because it is a more  popular, even if more vulgar,  way of pronouncing 'cesso',  more confidential, it can be used with friends or on a site as Instagram, to give more emphasis, more 'colour . As if one suddenly becomes to speak  dialect, but this is not dialect, is a corruption of Italian. It is not in a dictionary, of course, but in spoken everyday language often there are such corruptions/modifications.

Comment: Anyway, I think that the person who wrote the phrase wanted say cess', truncated, I guess that this was the idea of pronounciation. Not 'cesse' pronouncing the final 'e'.

Comment: Thanks i heard ber pronounce cesse with the final  e. This is exactly what she meant as you wrote in your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. These are personal variations without particular meaning or importance. Just are things that happen in spoken everyday language, of course it is not standard italian.